# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - Server is ASP.NET | Client is ReactJS

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, json, api

I'm trying to fetch an API I'm developing in C#, consuming the data in ReactJS on the client-side, but I'm having a strange problem. When I make the requests through the Postman / Thunder Client they happen without any problem, they return a JSON with the correct data and the status 200.

The same happens in the Network tab, in the DevTools of Google Chrome, status 200 with Review and Response showing the data correct, but the console is reporting the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Check the code shown here below:

CLIENT-SIDE

```
export const USER_GET = () => {
    return {
        url: 'https://localhost:7282/api/Person',
        options: {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: "no-cors",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      };
}
```

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        const getDataFromApi = async () => {
            const {url, options} = USER_GET();
            const request = await fetch(url, options);
            const response = await request.json()
            console.log(response)
        }
        getDataFromApi()
    }, [])
```

Response in Postman:

```
[
    {
        "idPerson": 1,
        "name": "Dados provisórios",
        "cpf": "99.999.999-99",
        "addres": "Rua Provisória",
        "district": "Bairro",
        "city": "Provisória",
        "cep": "55555-555",
        "email": "user@email.com",
        "phoneNumber": "5555555555",
        "birthDate": "1997-03-17T00:00:00"
    }
]

Status: 200 OK
Size: 238 Bytes
Time: 313 ms
```

> FormRegister.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at FormRegister.js:12:1) at getDataFromApi

[image: Network with status 200]

[image: Preview]

SERVER-SIDE

```
namespace ApiSpacenet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {
        static List<Person>Persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {
                IdPerson = 1,
                Name="Dados provisórios",
                Cpf = "99.999.999-99",
                Addres = "Rua Provisória",
                City = "Provisória",
                District = "Bairro",
                Cep = "55555-555",
                Email = "user@email.com",
                PhoneNumber = "5555555555",
                BirthDate = new DateTime(1997, 3, 17),
            },
        };

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
        {
            return Ok(Persons);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone here help?

Answer (score 0):

Opaque response.

"A response for a no-cors request to a cross-origin resource has a response type of 'opaque'".

We need to enable CORS support on the server-side.

```
app.UseCors(c =>
{
    c.AllowAnyHeader();
    c.AllowAnyMethod();
    c.AllowAnyOrigin();
});
```

Apply the code above in the file Program.cs